# time-out error while installing pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to download pip to my computer and I get time-out error. (I'm following this link: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip )
Someone knows what to do?

This is what I run:

```
C:\Users\gshelef\Desktop>python get-pip.py
```

The error:

> Collecting pip Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None)) after   connection broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(
>   object at 0x0000000003E3EF28>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org
>   timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/`

Note, I have 3.3.2 Python version

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Does `ping pypi.python.org` succeed?

Comment: Can you access `pypi.python.org` with your browser? If so, are you using a HTTP/HTTPS proxy?

Comment: tried to run  'ping pypi.python.org' and got : Pinging python.map.fastly.net [199.27.79.223] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 199.27.79.223:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Answer (score 2):

prepare pip, setuptools and wheel in local dir(e.g ./), and you can install pip without internet.
python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=./

reference: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2351

Comment: Running from the Spyder IDE, I had to edit `get-pip.py` and manually add `--no-index` and `--find-links=./` to the list of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to IP6 vs IP4 connection to `pypi.org`
I have followed [this answer](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/pypa/pip/9508/767124918) to force IP4 for this server in hosts file
and it solved the problem.
Altogether I have added to host:

```
151.101.192.223 pypi.org
151.101.193.63  files.pythonhosted.org
```